# Concatenate two php commands

Tags: magento-1.9, php, title

I'm not sure if I've used the correct terminology but this is what I want to achieve.

I want to combine two php "commands" to output the title tag as follows:

So the title shows "Shoes by Nike"

The code I'm using is

```
title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?> by <?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('company'); ?>"
```

Where `<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>` brings up shoes

and `<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('company'); ?>"` brings up company

Comment: Did you mean this? title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName().' by '.$_product->getAttributeText('company')) ?>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName().'by'. $_product->getAttributeText('company')) ?>"
```

Answer (score 1):

What i just understand is, you want to output **Shoes by Nike**, You are getting Shoes from different function and Nike from different function, and you want to concatenate these two.
It can be done like that.

```
$prod_name = $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName());
$company = $_product->getAttributeText('company');
echo $prod_name." by ".$company;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append the string and add in your title

```
$title = $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) . "by" . $_product->getAttributeText('company');
```

Add it in your html part

```
title="<?php echo $title; ?>"
```